Oncotic pressure and saline solution
I have read that if the oncotic pressure and the hydrostatic pressure aren't equal, either filtration or resorption happens.
I would like to know, why the effect of inorganic salts is not brought into account. I guess it is because they form 1% of blood plasma, whereas proteins about 7%. But still it seems large enough that it shouldn't be neglected.
But if the inorganic salts are negligible, why is 0.9% saline solution said to be isotonic if it doesn't contain any proteins. Wouldn't the saline solution lower the oncotic pressure and cause swelling of surrounding tissues and erythrocytes bursting?
Why does oncotic pressure neglect the inorganic salts whereas saline solution cares only about those?

oncotic pressure is by definition the osmotic pressure caused by colloidal dissolved proteins. Osmotic pressure caused by inorganic salts is not involved by oncotic pressure by definition. // OTOH tonicity is the osmotic pressure caused by components not permeating the membrane.
So oncotic pressure is a part of tonicity which is part of osmotic pressure.

OK, I guess the so called filtration pressure only contains the oncotic pressure as the inorganic salts can pass through the glomerulus and don't affect its filtration rate. I understand the role of the oncotic pressure. But why is it said to be OK to inject saline into the blood? It's 0,9% and normal blood plasma is 1% salts AND PLUS ALL THE PROTEINS THAT AFFECT THE TONICITY. It wouldn't be completely isotonic if the saline has the same amount of salt and lacks the proteins. What am I missing? Thank you.

Are you sure about the summary molar ion concentrations of plasma ions, compared to 0.9% NaCl? As these percentages are mass, not molar quantities. I got the opposite relative numbers.

The saline's NaCl should be 0,154 mol/l. The blood NaCl that I found should be 0,14 mol/l. Anyway, I think the saline would still dilute blood proteins so I don't get how it maintains the same tonicity.

Do not forget other ions, mainly bicarbonate.
